# Import / include assigned variables in Jinja2

Tags: import, include, jinja2

In Jinja2, how can one access assigned variables (i.e. `{% set X=Y %}`) within files incorporated with `include`?

I'd expect the following to work given two Jinja2 files:

`A.jinja`:

```
Stuff
{% include 'B.jinja' -%}
B has {{ N }} references
```

`B.jinja`:

```
{% set N = 12 %}
```

I'd expect that `A.jinja`, when compiled with Jinja2, would produce the following output:

```
Stuff 
B has 12 references
```

However, it produces:

```
Stuff
B has  references
```

I'd be much obliged for any input as to how to access the Jinja2 variables, such as `N` above, in the file that includes the file where `N` is set.

Thank you for reading.

Brian

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There's a difference between `include` and `import`, although you should be able to do both.

- `include 'B.jinja` simply renders the template and ignores any variable assignments or macros within it.
- `import 'B.jinja' as B`, imports `B` as if it were a module, so you have to output `B.N`.
- `from 'B.jinja' import N` imports variable `N` directly.

Change your import line to the last option and see if that fixes things.  If you need more help, look at [the documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#import).

Comment: Shouldn't that last line be `from 'B.jinja' import N`?